# How to use Apache Spark as backend for Web-Application instead of Postgres

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, database

I have an Web App which uses **Postgres** as backend database. Currently the data is not that huge. But eventually it will be increasing and will be having *big data*.

Is it possible to migrate the current database- **Postgres** to **Apache Spark** as a backend for faster access of data?

***e.g*** Can I use Spark-SQL for access of data so that I don't have to change the code much.

Are there any other solutions I can think of to access the data faster from database?

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Spark is not a database. It is used in conjunction with a database. PostgreSQL can likely scale just fine up into the tens of terabytes or more, but it depends on the use cases. See posts such as http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24034/scalability-limitations-of-postgresql-and-mysql

Answer (score 3):

Spark IS NOT a database engine. It however allows you to run SQL queries on data you have.

In my opinion there are few options for you:

1. You can read data in Spark with Hive support enabled and expose
   HiveThriftServer, then you can invoke SQL queries from other
   applications. However it will not be a backend for Postgres, just
   another application you will use. Data will not be transfered to
   Postgres automatically, but stored in Hive metastore and you will have to create functions to transfer data from Spark cache/Hive metastore to Postgres, i.e. by using Spark Structured Streaming with JDBC sink. It's quite complicated to fully describe proposed solution, however it's not much hard to write. If you want additional explanation, please comment my answer :)
2. In my opinion Data Grid will be better in your situation. I really like Spark, however i.e. Coherence can write all cache to database in async queue, so you've got consistency and very high speed.

It very depends what kind of service you will be creating :) If you use batch jobs/streaming jobs and write results to Postres i.e. every hour, Spark with SQL will be good. If you want faster updates in Postres, I will recommend some Data Grid, such as Coherence or Apache Ignite

Comment: @Gaweda, Thanks for the answer. It is really helpful. Can you illustrate more about the answer? I want to implement Spark for backend for website as per requirement. So it would be  helpful if you can explain more.